# Get True or False from dict and key's existence

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a boolean `True` or `False` value based on whether a dict exists (is not `None`) and if it contains a value.

This is my code. I would expect `enabled == False` but it is assigned the value of `cfg`.

```
In [105]: cfg = {}

In [106]: is_enabled = cfg and cfg.get('enabled')

In [107]: is_enabled
Out[107]: {}
```

Why is `is_enabled == {}`? This must be an obvious mistake but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you actually want to have to rewrite it

```
is_enabled = True if (cfg and cfg.get('enabled')) else False
```

`cfg` only evaluates to False in a boolean context like `if cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of short-circuit boolean operators.  In the expression `cfg and ANYTHING`, since cfg is empty it has a boolean value of False.  Therefore the second operand is never evaluated.  The result of the expression is the first operand, which is `{}`.  Note that the expression `0 and None` has a value of 0, but the expression `1 and None` has a value of None!

Perhaps you want the line to read `is_enabled = bool(cfg) and cfg.get('enabled')` or even just `is_enabled = cfg.get('enabled',False)`.

Comment: I understand short-circuit boolean operators, but I wouldn't expect a boolean comparison (`foo and bar`) to return the the value of the 1st operand. I would have expected a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
is_enabled = cfg is not None and 'enabled' in cfg
```

Comment: `cfg is not None` is better style than `cfg != None`.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I changed it, as you're right, that is usually the _pythonistic_ way, although I usually write the `!=` form in my own code.